# Creating a database trigger for each transaction MS Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know weather it is possible to create a trigger on the database that would put each query in a transaction which could then be rolled back if the query fails WITHOUT having to enclose every stored procedure with a begin transaction and end transaction bracket.
For example we have multiple stored procedures and none of them are enclosed in these brackets, so i want to know if it will be possible to do something like

```
--create trigger on database <mydb>
--execute the sql code here from what ever stored procedure
--begin catch
-- if it fails then rollback else commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to create a trigger at the database level to wrap each query execution in transaction.

These two articles will show the list of events or groups for which you can create db level triggers

[DDL Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx)

[DDL Event Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx)